# Remove CORS Accept-Encoding header on Safari

Tags: safari, http-headers, google-drive-api, cors

I made a javascript bookmarklet which accesses byte-shuffled images (whence I make ArrayBuffer CORS) on a publicly shared google-drive folder.
Works great on Firefox, Chrome, Opera, and even Safari 5.something (I run on windows).

However, one user told me it didn't work on Safari 7.0.3 (and I don't know if it works in Safari 6.something).

From what I understand the request cannot load because Safari adds an "Accept-Encoding" into the preflight, while google's Access-Control-Allow-Headers doesn't mention this header.

Since I don't think I can alter myself google's Access-Control-Allow-Headers, is it possible to nullify this header on the browser's side? (specifically, on Safari's side ^^).
I can't test that myself, that's why I ask here.

Comment: We're encountering the same issue. It seems that Google Drive issues a series of redirects from the public URL we request to the one which is delivered, and along the way, Safari gets cranky about CORS. A work-around is to use the terminal URL in the redirect chain, but I can't figure out how to use JavaScript to find the terminal URL.

Comment: And today the problem seems to have gone away.

Comment: Google is not redirecting.  Guess I will be happy with that.

Comment: and it's back again! ugh.

Comment: If anyone finds a solution to this, PLEASE post it here.

Comment: I just use a redirect resolver server-side. Make a CORS call to your own server, which tries the url and send back the final redirected one.

Comment: @doonge. I had been stuck on a similar problem for days. thank you so much for that tip!

Comment: I've been able to replicate this bug and have raised it with the engineering team.

Comment: Is this problem related to requests with redirects? I recently encountered something similar, and found that if I added a slash to the request it would work without such an error. [This answer by Anne](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39354692/1468366) suggests this might be a bug in Safari, in response to [a lengthy question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39354408/1468366).