# Enable more permissive CORS headers on public Google Drive files

Tags: google-drive-api, cors

The [authoring tool](http://storymap.knightlab.com/select.html) for our [StoryMap](http://storymap.knightlab.com) tool is pure HTML/JS, using Google for authentication, and specifically using Google Drive to store the JSON files users create with the tool.

The tool functions by publishing (with the user's permission) a JSON file on Google Drive ('public on the web'), with the expectation being that the general public will be able to load the JSON (through their browser, of course).

This has worked, until recently, when the request  for the JSON file has been redirected to another URL. It seems that, only when redirected, Safari adds `accept-encoding` to  `Access-Control-Request-Headers`

It works OK if Safari requests the ultimate file, but I don't know of a reliable way to get that URL.

Any ideas? (Besides don't use Google Drive...)

Comment: What is the error you get when Safari adds this Access-Control-Request-Headers?

Comment: We implemented a proxy to get around this so I can't produce the exact error, but basically, the server doesn't tell Safari that it accepts that header, so Safari raises the standard cross server security error.

Comment: Follow it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175638/remove-cors-accept-encoding-header-on-safari

Comment: I've been able to replicate this bug and have raised it with the engineering team.